# Elements css animation resets if i move it using js style.bottom

Tags: javascript, css

I have created a notification system with JavaScript. Everything works fine except the fade-out animation (`notification-anim`). If a new notification is displayed, the previous notifications animation will be reset, and notification window will start fading out from the start again. But each should fade out 5 seconds exactly after it's displayed. And if there are no notifications in the last 5 seconds, notification container gets overwritten with `innerHTML = '';` and notifCount goes back to 0.
Why is this happening, and is there a solution for this?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MiloSx7/ojjjnmpc/)

I have tried to explain everything as best as i could

Comment: I think the animation is getting lost because of the line 16: elem('notifContainer').innerHTML += notif; // Inject HTML, this is overrading the previous elements and inserts them again. Also, if you want that the animation changes, you must set opacity to 0, and then change it to 1.

Comment: The animation seems to be working ok, and you were right. I console logged that elements innerHTML and indeed, it gets overwritten. But why does `innerHTML += notif;` overwrites the content? Shouldn't it just "add" more in the container? Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: To insert a new div, you can do this. 1) create the new div with createElement: var newDiv = document.createElement("div"). 2) Insert the div content: newDiv.innerHTML = "you content htm". 3) Append the new element: elem('notifContainer').appendChild(newDiv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning a new value to [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) has the following effect:

> Removes all of element's children, parses the content string and
>   assigns the resulting nodes as children of the element.

This of course causes all animations of these elements to play again.

One solution is to use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead:

> [Element.insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) - An alternative for innerHTML, allowing
>   you to append the new HTML, instead of replacing it.

Your code will then look as follows:

```
elem('notifContainer').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', notif);
elem('notif' + notifCount).style.animation = 'notification-anim 5s ease-in forwards';
```

Note the additional `forwards` in the CSS animation to stop the animation once it's completed.

PS: If you are wondering why `innerHTML += notif` doesn't just 'append' but performs a regular assignment of a completely new value: `a += b` is 'just' a shorthand notation of `a = a + b` (according to the specification https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#prod-AssignmentOperator).

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for the nice explanation

Comment: Thanks! Most of the explanation is actually quoted from Mozilla's [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) - a pretty good resource for any JavaScript developer.